# Cannot install File::HomeDir using cpan on MacOS Mojave for MacTex

Tags: xcode, latex

I am trying to setup [LaTeX Workshop Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=James-Yu.latex-workshop) for Visual Studio Code. I have [The MacTeX-2018 Distribution](https://www.tug.org/mactex/) that I installed [using Homebrew cask](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/155081/172865).  I cannot setup formatting. Errors lead me to the [answer for the GitHub LaTeX-Workshop issue](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/376#issuecomment-372497291). First three commands worked just well for me:

```
sudo cpan Unicode::GCString
sudo cpan App::cpanminus
sudo cpan YAML::Tiny
```

Unfortunately, trying to execute the last one (I also tried `sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install "File::HomeDir"'` gives and error and one unsatisfied dependency:

```
Vitaliis-MacBook-Pro:~ vitalii$ sudo cpan File::HomeDir
Reading '/Users/vitalii/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 01 Nov 2018 08:29:03 GMT
Running install for module 'File::HomeDir'
Running make for R/RE/REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.004.tar.gz
Checksum for /Users/vitalii/.cpan/sources/authors/id/R/RE/REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.004.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building R/RE/REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.004.tar.gz

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Warning: prerequisite Mac::SystemDirectory 0.04 not found.
Writing Makefile for File::HomeDir
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
---- Unsatisfied dependencies detected during ----
----     REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.004.tar.gz    ----
    Mac::SystemDirectory [requires]
Running make test
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running make install
  Delayed until after prerequisites
Running install for module 'Mac::SystemDirectory'
Running make for E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.10.tar.gz
Checksum for /Users/vitalii/.cpan/sources/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.10.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.10.tar.gz

HASCOMPILERuX_i/TEST5U_g.c:2:10: fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found
#include "EXTERN.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Couldn't execute cc  -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -Os "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   -c HASCOMPILERuX_i/TEST5U_g.c -o HASCOMPILERuX_i/TEST5U_g.o: Inappropriate ioctl for device at Makefile.PL line 14.
Requires a compiler
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
  ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.10.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
Running make for R/RE/REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.004.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory /Users/vitalii/.cpan/build/File-HomeDir-1.004-KoTD4b

  CPAN.pm: Building R/RE/REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.004.tar.gz

Warning: Prerequisite 'Mac::SystemDirectory => 0.04' for 'REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.004.tar.gz' failed when processing 'ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.10.tar.gz' with 'writemakefile => NO '/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL' returned status 6400'. Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited.
cp lib/File/HomeDir/FreeDesktop.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/FreeDesktop.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Driver.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Driver.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Unix.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Unix.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Windows.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Windows.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/MacOS9.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/MacOS9.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Test.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Test.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin/Carbon.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin/Carbon.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin/Cocoa.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir/Darwin/Cocoa.pm
cp lib/File/HomeDir.pm blib/lib/File/HomeDir.pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::HomeDir::Darwin::Cocoa.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::HomeDir::MacOS9.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::HomeDir::Darwin.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::HomeDir.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::HomeDir::FreeDesktop.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::HomeDir::Unix.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::HomeDir::Darwin::Carbon.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::HomeDir::Test.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::HomeDir::Driver.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/File::HomeDir::Windows.3pm
  REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.004.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t xt/*.t
t/01_compile.t ........ 1/11 # Implemented by: File::HomeDir::Darwin
t/01_compile.t ........ ok     
t/02_main.t ........... # $<: 0 -- $(: 0 0 1 2 3 4 5 8 9 12 20 29 61 80 33 98 100 204 250 395 398 399 701
t/02_main.t ........... ok     
t/10_test.t ........... ok     
t/11_darwin.t ......... ok   
t/12_darwin_carbon.t .. skipped: Not running on 32-bit Darwin
t/13_darwin_cocoa.t ... skipped: Not running on Darwin with Cocoa API using Mac::SystemDirectory
t/20_empty_home.t ..... ok   
All tests successful.
Files=7, Tests=90,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr  0.01 sys +  0.40 cusr  0.08 csys =  0.52 CPU)
Result: PASS
  REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.004.tar.gz
Tests succeeded but one dependency not OK (Mac::SystemDirectory)
  REHSACK/File-HomeDir-1.004.tar.gz
  [dependencies] -- NA
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
```

I also tried to install the mentioned unsatisfied dependency. Again, I faced the following error trying to install **Mac::SystemDirectory** module using **cpan**:

```
Vitaliis-MacBook-Pro:~ vitalii$ sudo cpan Mac::SystemDirectory
Password:
Reading '/Users/vitalii/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Thu, 01 Nov 2018 08:29:03 GMT
Running install for module 'Mac::SystemDirectory'
Running make for E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.10.tar.gz
Checksum for /Users/vitalii/.cpan/sources/authors/id/E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.10.tar.gz ok

  CPAN.pm: Building E/ET/ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.10.tar.gz

HASCOMPILERRgwh/TESTb9zf.c:2:10: fatal error: 'EXTERN.h' file not found
#include "EXTERN.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Couldn't execute cc  -g -pipe -fno-common -DPERL_DARWIN -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector -Os "-I/System/Library/Perl/5.18/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE"   -c HASCOMPILERRgwh/TESTb9zf.c -o HASCOMPILERRgwh/TESTb9zf.o: Inappropriate ioctl for device at Makefile.PL line 14.
Requires a compiler
Warning: No success on command[/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL]
'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
  ETHER/Mac-SystemDirectory-0.10.tar.gz
  /usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL -- NOT OK
Running make test
  Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
  Make had some problems, won't install
```

My OS is **MacOS Mojave 10.14**.
I have **xCode version 10.1** installed.
I have **make** installed:

```
Vitaliis-MacBook-Pro:~ vitalii$ make -v
GNU Make 3.81
Copyright (C) 2006  Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.
There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A
PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

This program built for i386-apple-darwin11.3.0
```

I also have **clang** compiler

```
Vitaliis-MacBook-Pro:~ vitalii$ cc -v
Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.10.44.2)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.0.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

As I head some problems after updating to Mojave (could not use git), I already followed instructions in the answer for [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/macos-mojave-invalid-active-developer-path).
Could you help me with that?
**Related Links:**
https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=127028 
https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/issues/376

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the exact same problem and found a workaround:

1. Install the current version of Perl using Homebrew: `brew install perl`
2. Check if `xcode-select -p` points to the Command Line Tools. If not, run `xcode-select --switch /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools`
3. Install Mac::SystemDirectory using cpan (not cpanm): `cpan Mac::SystemDirectory`

I have no experience with Perl and I have no idea why this worked, but it did :)