# How can I determine the sound volume from within a python script?

Tags: macos, python, sound-volume, monitoring

I need to see when the sound volume on my Mac hits a certain point, in Python (and preferably without the need of any permissions). Any pointers appreciated.

Comment: When posting coding questions, please share what you already have, and/or have tried to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of approaches you can use here.

#### AppleScript via `osascript` CLI

You can use AppleScript directly via the `osascript` CLI to get and set the volume like so:

*Get volume - Echos a number from 0 to 100*

```
$ osascript -e 'output volume of (get volume settings)'
```

*Set volume - Where 50 is a number from 0 to 100*

```
$ osascript -e 'set volume output volume 50'
```

*Get mute state - Echos a string of 'true' or 'false'*

```
$ osascript -e 'output muted of (get volume settings)'
```

*Set mute state - Where 'true' can be 'true' or 'false'*

```
$ osascript -e 'set volume output muted true'
```

#### Using `osascript` module in Python

If you have Python3 installed and Xcode you can install the `osascript` module like so:

*Install Xcode*

```
$ xcode-select --install
```

*Install `virtualenv`*

```
$ pip3 install virtualenv
```

*Create a Virtualenv project, and activate it*

```
$ virtualenv venv
$ . venv/bin/activate
```

*Now within this custom Virtualenv environment, install Python module*

```
$ pip3 install osascript
Collecting osascript
Collecting public (from osascript)
Collecting runcmd (from osascript)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages (from osascript) (41.0.1)
Collecting temp (from osascript)
Collecting psutil (from runcmd->osascript)
Installing collected packages: public, psutil, runcmd, temp, osascript
Successfully installed osascript-2019.4.13 psutil-5.6.1 public-2019.4.13 runcmd-2019.4.13 temp-2019.4.13
```

*Here's an example Python program that will set the volume to 100*

```
$ cat vol.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import osascript

osascript.run("set volume output volume 100")
code, out, err = osascript.run("output volume of (get volume settings)")
print(out)
```

*Running this will set to 100 and then display the volume's level*

```
$ ./vol.py
100
```

#### References

- [How to change volume with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772011/how-to-change-volume-with-python)
- [Pipenv & Virtual Environments](https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/)
- [Why am I getting an “invalid active developer path” when attempting to use Git after upgrading to macOS Catalina?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/254380/why-am-i-getting-an-invalid-active-developer-path-when-attempting-to-use-git-a)
- [Set/get OSX volume/mute from the command line](https://coderwall.com/p/22p0ja/set-get-osx-volume-mute-from-the-command-line)
- [PyPi - osascript](https://pypi.org/project/osascript/)